# How to get the message value of a nested exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I have an exception that looks like this:

`exc = ProtocolError('Connection Aborted', BadStatusLine('No status line received'))`

how can I access the `No status line received` part?

Here's the example situation:

```
def some_function():
    raise ProtocolError('Connection Aborted', BadStatusLine('No status line received'))

def some_other_function():
    try:
        some_function()
    except Exception as exc:
        if exc.message:
            details = exc.message
        else:
            details = exc
```

In the code above I'm trying to check if the returned exception has a message and if so I'm supposed to write it into the database, however when I call the `exc.message` it returns an empty string, and when I call `exc` it returns:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object:
> ProtocolError('Connection Aborted', BadStatusLine('No status linereceived',)), of type: <class 'urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError'>

so I cant write it into the database since its a type `Exception` not `string`, what I need to do is to see if the returned Exception has another nested Exception in it and get it's message.

Comment: is this exception is in string format?

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin `type: <class 'urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError'>`

Comment: can you provide the code to reproduce the problem . so that it can be quicly answered and solved

Comment: done, check it out please

Comment: ProtocolError is not defined . .from where you are using or importing this function? urllib3?

Comment: yes `ProtocolError` is from `urllib3` and `BadStatusLine` is from `httplib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the exact optimal way to fetch the inner message or exception but for quick assistance i wrote a utility function which by using regular expressions will return you inner exceptions or messages complete code is following

```
from urllib3.exceptions import ProtocolError
from http.client import BadStatusLine
import re

def FetchInnerExceptions(exc):
    result = []
    messages = str(exc).split(',')
    for msg in messages:
        m = re.search('''(?<=')\s*[^']+?\s*(?=')''', msg)
        if m is not None or m != '':
            result.append(m.group().strip())
    return result

def some_function():
    raise ProtocolError('Connection Aborted', BadStatusLine('No status line received'))

def some_other_function():
    try:
        some_function()
    except Exception as exc:
        e = FetchInnerExceptions(exc)
        print(e) #dumps all array or use index e[1] for your required message

some_other_function()
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I think I made it work, i just used `details = str(exc)` in the last line and grabbed the whole record for the database, but I will check out your solution and maybe use it if that doesn't work :)

Comment: ok just in case if it worked then don't forget to mark this as accepted to help others